# iphone ios 7 homescreen mask isn't applied correctly to my icon

Tags: ios, iphone

My problem is that my application's icon seems to be resized to fit the rounded-corner mask applied when displayed on the home screen.

EDIT: Here's the image:

[image]

My image follows the guidelines in these locations (mainly that it is 120x120, and doesn't have pre-rounded corners):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW4

I've tried:

1) Using an image catalog

2) Searching for the issue on this site.  I looked through the first 5 paginations sorted by newest and can't find anyone who's had the issue...

3) Making sure that the image is specified in the info.plist

4) Checking the troubleshooting app icon issues on the apple developer site.

The icon always ends up drawn with the black edges.

Is there a way to programmatically make sure the mask is applied correctly?

Has someone else encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have the wrong DPI set in the icon PNG—if it’s something other than 72 (the screen’s nominal DPI in points), the system may be trying to scale it to match.

Comment: This is probably it. You also can now post an image since you have 13 rep! That would help us diagnose it.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try that.  I went ahead and added the image.  Hooray 10 rep!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the DPI was correct.  The problem was that there was a transparent background layer, wider than the image that Android Studio seemed to have added when it was run through that deployment process.  The layer went unnoticed in preview because it doesn't highlight the transparency. Noticed it when I opened it in GIMP.

So it was a silly oversight on my part.